# Porque las tarjetas no me quedan mas anchas en react usando bootstraps, ademas puse 4 tarjetas por renglon y quedan 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
  `  const Item = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row-cols-md-4 g-4">
      <div className="col">
        <div className="card">
          <p className="card-title text-center card-header">{item?.marca}</p>
          <img
            src={item?.pictureURL}
            alt={item?.pictureURL}
            className="card-img-top"
          />
          <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card-text">Modelo: {item?.model}</p>
          </div>

          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center pb-3">
            <Link to={`/detail/${item?.id}`}>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark">
                <strong>Ver detalles</strong>
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola buenas esta clase es errónea: row-cols-md-4 g-4

Necesitas aplicar la clase card-columns, adjunto link a la doc:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

Esto creará automáticamente el grid que necesitas para que haya columnas

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Si te ha servido añade la respuesta como correcta!

Comment: Hecho gracias!!